# open a url and using its search function based on keywords in a text file does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to open a website and use its search  function based on a couple of keywords. Below is the code that I have written and do not know why it does not work! I get no error but the page is not shown either! Any help appreciated!

```
subset of keywords: "subvalv stenosis pulm"[All Search Fields] OR 
"subvalvular pulmonary stenoses"[All Search Fields] OR "subvalvular 
pulmonary stenosis"[All Search Fields] OR "subvalvular pulmonic stenosis"
[All Search Fields] 

# https://datamed.org/search.php?
searchtype=data&query=%22Cancer%22&offset=1&repository=0003
#repository:means the repository that I would like to be searched with the 
        deired keywords
#number of pages
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
keyword_array = []
with open('localDrive\\miniized.txt') as my_keywordfile:
        line=my_keywordfile.readline().strip()
s="?searchtype=data&query="
last="&offset=1&repository=0003"
line2=s.strip()+line+last.strip()


url = 'https://datamed.org/search.php?'
values = { 'query': line2 }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
url = '?'.join([url, data])
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: What do you mean, the page is not shown? Where are you doing anything to show a page? What are you doing with `response`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with print functions? See if the actual url is correct, if the data looks correct etc.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I am new to python, just searched how I can show the content of a page and found  this code. Should I do something else to see the page?

Comment: This is code to fetch the content of a page. If yourl want to actually see it, you'll need to print it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to @Daniel Roseman by saying:This is code to fetch the content of a page. If yourl want to actually see it, you'll need to print it somewhere